# create launcher Icon - matlab

Tags: launcher, matlab

I installed Matlab (almost) according to the guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB. I chose the installation folder ~/opt/MATLAB instead of their chosen /usr/local/MATLAB. I also found that I did not mark the "Create symbolic links to Matlab scripts in  /usr/local/bin".

When I go through their short section that describes how to add Matlab to the launcher, I find that it does not work (no error message). The application is just not appearing in the "applications" window.

Since I am new to Linux, I wanted to ask whether it has something to do with the fact that I installed it somewhere else than them?

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use terminal to open my MATLAB but if you want to create launcher icon in applications or desktop, I think you can use mathworks solutions below.

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20-how-do-i-make-a-desktop-launcher-for-matlab-in-linux

Here, multiple people have described ways to add MATLAb icon to desktop on LINUX. I hope it works for you.